# coloring bar charts in matplotlib depending on dcitionary key value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

i have a dictionary of devices and their battery level , what i'm trying to do here is to plot histogram showing the battery level with colors , red if the battery is under 20 , 20<yellow<60 and green >60

i'm using matplotlib, pyplot and im trying to iterate over the key values in my dictionary but im getting a syntax error in my for loop (can i loop over keys and set the color value for every bar ?) , i'm not sure what im doing wrong  , this is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic={'Door1':50,'Hall':20,'Garage':90,'Door101':15}


i=0
for i in dic.keys()
    if dic.keys(i) <20:
        color='r'
    if 20<dic.keys(i) >=60 
        color='y'
    if dic.keys(i) >=90
        color='g
    i=i+1


plt.bar(range(len(dic)), list(dic.values()), align='center' , color=color)  
plt.xticks(range(len(dic)), list(dic.keys())) 

plt.title('Battery Level')
#save my plot as a png file to insert in Ifram html later
plt.savefig('my_plot.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {'Door1': 50, 'Hall': 20, 'Garage': 90, 'Door101': 15}

color = []

for i in dic.keys():
    if dic[i] < 20:
        color.append('red')
    if 20 <= dic[i] <= 60:
        color.append('yellow')
    if dic[i] >= 90:
        color.append('green')

plt.bar(range(len(dic)), list(dic.values()), align='center', color=color)
plt.xticks(range(len(dic)), list(dic.keys())) 

plt.title('Battery Level')
# save my plot as a png file to insert in Ifram html later
plt.savefig('my_plot.png')
```

Output:
[image]